# Collada (.dae) file imported to XCode shows without textures

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, collada

I imported a .dae file that I downloaded from cgtrader to XCode to use with ARKit. However, When I visualize it, it shows without textures:

[image]

The materials seem to be there (file tree shows them):

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong, or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you select the materials in the "Diffuse" property of the scene graph, see the image attached here

[image: dragonius]

Comment: Would it work if there is more than one files for the materials? Or would it have to be all on the same texture file

Comment: Separated files per material can be included but just one can be pointed by the "Diffuse" property, it should be possible to change it at run time indeed.

Comment: if helpful it would be nice form you to accept the answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks.. done. Would also appreciate the upvote if you think other users might benefit from the question.